# Adding/Edit a pod file after initial init "firebase"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, cocoapods, xcode8

So when I installed the pod file into my project I forgot to add in FirebaseDatabase and now I want to add it in how do I do that? Will going through the pod init process again mess things up?

Photo Of My Pod File:

[image: ScreenShot]

Comment: please also add your code as text (in code block) in addition / instead of image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Should just add the new pod you want, and run:

```
 pod install
```

And it would work, and won`t mess up you code.

Iy will Update (If necessary) Older Pods, and Install New Ones.
You should not Run pod init, just pod install.